# Get files from a folder in Power Automate is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, error, power-automate, flow

I am querying all files from a given folder in Power Automate. I have used the below in the filter query of Get Items action:

```
{FullPath} eq 'GSD Test Document Library/DS0001'
```

[image: Files in Folder]

But while running the flow, getting the below error:

> The $filter expression "{FullPath} eq 'GSD Test Document Library/DS0001'" is not valid. Creating query failed.

What is invalid in the filter query?

Note: I don't want to use the REST API, want to get using SharePoint action.

Comment: As per this comment, you won't be able to filter items based on`{FullPath}` property: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/power-automate-get-files-properties-only-filter-query-not/m-p/610860/highlight/true#M80792

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the limitations of using filter queries in SharePoint actions inside Power automate flows when column names have `{ }` in it.

So, filter query will not work for properties like `{FullPath}`, `{Path}`, `{Name}`, etc.

---

As you want to get files from a specific folder in SharePoint document library using Power Automate flow, you can use **List folder** action like below:

[image]

OR you have to use the SharePoint REST API and "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action in Power automate.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh - I am aware of the List Folder and "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action (getfolderbyserverrelativeurl" - the problem in both the method is - it doesn't bring the custom columns, content type details from the document library which is needed. It only brings out of the file properties.

Comment: Do you want custom column values against files (properties)? What content type details you need exactly, content type name/ID of each file item?

Comment: Yes - I want each column details from each content type from the given path.